# Rewriting LEFT JOIN sort of LINQ into generic LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've got this LINQ to return set of records that are present in one set, but are missing from the other:

```
var fieldsToDelete = (from field in externalContactsInvolvedFromDb
                                      let item = externalContactsInvolved.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MeetingExternalContactInvolvedId == field.MeetingExternalContactInvolvedId)
                                      where item == null
                                      select field)
                                      .ToList();
```

externalContactsInvolvedFromDb and externalContactsInvolved are lists of objects of the same type. Here I'm returning list of objects from externalContactsInvolvedFromDb that are not present in the other set, based on the Primary Key (MeetingExternalContactInvolvedId).

Now, this logic is repeated in many places in my solution so I decided to rewrite it into a generic method. Unfortunately, I'm completely stuck. I've come up with something like this ('U' is the generic type for ExternalContactInvolved):

```
    string relatedEntityPK = "MeetingExternalContactInvolvedId";
    var x2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(U), "i");
    var y2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(U), "meeting");
    var equalExp2 = Expression.Equal(
                        Expression.Property(x2, relatedEntityPK),
                        Expression.Property(y2, relatedEntityPK)
                        );
    var lambda2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<U, bool>>(equalExp2, x2);
```

Using this I could write this:

```
_context.Set<U>.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(lambda)
```

But, naturally, it won't compare two datasets and will return error of not being able to generate WHERE clause. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Any reason why would you want to do that? Even if you manage to create this expression maintainability is lost.

Comment: I use this logic in multiple places in my entire solution and the only difference between the appliances is the classes used. Instead of copying this into 10-20-30 almost exactly the same methods I figured it will be better to have one generic method.
I think that maintaining one complicated method (which won't need many adjustments anyway) is better than maintaining 30 simple methods.

Comment: How do you think general function should looks like? Which parameters? At first convert your query to the method chain and then try to simulate. Anyway, I think you have to use LEFT JOIN instead of FirstOrDefault.

Answer (score 1):

So you have two sequences of fairly similar types, and you want an extension method that returns all items from the first sequence that are not in the second sequence.

Normally you would use LINQ's method Except for this:

```
IQueryable<Customer> customers = ...
IQueryable<Customer> maleCustomers = ...
var femaleCustomers = customers.Except(maleCustomers);
```

However, you don't want to check on complete equality, you want to give some properties and say that if the values of the properties of the first set is also one of the properties in the second set, then don't include in the return value.

So input: sequences source1 and source2, two keySelectors, that select a key for every source1 item and every source2 item. Output: all source1 items that have a key that is not in any of the source2 keys.

To do this: make a query that selects the keys or all source2 items, and return all source1 items that have a key that is not contained in the source2 key items.

```
public static IQueryable<T1> Except<T1, T2, TKey>(
    this IQueryable<T1> source1,
    IQueryable<T2> source2,

   // KeySelectors: what values to use to determine that it should not be in the return?
   Expression<Func<T1, TKey>> key1Selector,
   Expression<Func<T2, TKey>> key2Selector)
{
    IQueryable<TKey> source2KeyItems = source2.Select(source2Item => key2Selector(source2Item));
    return source.Where(source1Item => !source2KeyItems.Contains(key1Selector(source1Item));
}
```

In words: make a query that selects from every element of sequence source2 the key as defined in key2Selector. This key is of type TKey. Do not execute the query yet.

Then, from every element of sequence source1, select the key of the same type TKey, using key1Selector. Keep only those elements of source, where the key isn't contained in the keys in the first query.

If you want you can put this into one big LINQ. You can also create an overload

```
public static IQueryable<T1> Except<T1, TKey>(
    this IQueryable<T1> source1,
    IQueryable<T2> source2,
   Expression<Func<T1, Key>> keySelector)
{
    return Except(source1, source2, keySelector, keySelector);
}
```

Usage:

> Here I'm returning list of objects from externalContactsInvolvedFromDb that are not present in the other set, based on the Primary Key (MeetingExternalContactInvolvedId).

```
IQueryable<Contacts> externalContactsInvolvedFromDb = ...
IQueryable<Contacts otherSet = ...
var externalsThatAreNotInOtherSetBasedOnPrimaryKey = externalContactsInvolvedFromDb.Except(

    otherSet,
    contact => contact.MeetingExternalContactInvolvedId, // use primary key
```

Comment: Thank you.
These two lines however:
IQueryable<TKey> source2KeyItems = source2.Select(source2Item => key2Selector(source2Item));
            return source1.Where(source1Item => !source2KeyItems.Contains(key1Selector(source1Item)));

contain "Method name expected" error (key1Selecttor and key2Selector are underlined). 
Do you know how can I overcome this?

Comment: Did you do *anything* to try to find the compiler error? Did you try to change `Key` in `Expression<Func<T2, Key>> key2Selector` into `TKey`. Maybe you should familiarize yourself with the concept of generic methods, so you can detect these typos yourself